# How to set certification in jenkins publish over ftp plug in?

Tags: jenkins-plugins

I have installed *Publish over FTP* plugin for Jenkins. There is checkbox named *Use FTP over TLS* which i have already checked. One another text-box named *Trusted Certificate*, but I don't know what value set here? How can I set the SSL here? I am using *Jenkins ver. 2.13*. Every time it show below error. My username and password are 100% correct. Don't know what I did wrong here.

> Error :  Failed to connect or change directory
>
> jenkins.plugins.publish_over.BapPublisherException: Failed to connect
>   and initialize FTP connection. Message:
>   [jenkins.plugins.publish_over.BapPublisherException: Failed to log in
>   with username [xxxxxx] - check username and password]

Answer (score 1):

What i did

- Open the server to connect in Firefox usting https://yourFtpServer.xx
- Check the encryption information in firefox (icon somewhere near the url)
- Safe the .pem-File
- open the pem file in text editor
  -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
  ....
  -----END CERTIFICATE-----
- copy/past the text above in "text-box named Trusted Certificate" in Jenkins